# Rails - can not access table from within rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am trying to create a rake task which queries an API and adds records to a table. However, I can not access that table (I get the following error).

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'exchange_rates'
```

My code is:

```
namespace :query_api do

  task get_currency_values: :environment do

    exchange_rate = ExchangeRate.new
    #some other code

  end

end
```

The code is located in

```
lib/tasks/query-api.rake
```

Comment: Dumb question but I have to ask. Does table 'exchange_rates' exist?

Comment: It appears in schema.rb & the server is running so I assume the table exists.

Comment: Perhaps the table exist in one environment (say "development") but not the other (say "production") ? If that is the case you might need to run your db migration on the environment where it does not exist to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with these other comments. This is a straightforward error. If you load up your rails console (`rails c`) in the environment in question (`development` or `production` or whatever) and type `ExchangeRate.new` then you should see the same error.

From there investigate the connection to the DB and make sure it's actually working.

Also, check which migrations have run in the environment where you're experiencing the error with `rake db:migrate:status`

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem(the record was being saved only in production). How can i make it such that the record is saved in development as well?

Comment: Check to make sure your `production` and `development` schemas have the same migrations run on them, and the schema matches. If they don't match (and it sure looks like they don't) then that will tell you the difference.